# have a problem accessing the files in wwwroot

Tags: asp.net-core

In the wwwroot folder I can access all files(images, java script, css, zip). But when I upload an apk file, it is not accessible.
When I compress this apk file to zip I can download it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AspNetCore uses this [list of media types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) and according to this list, it does not know what an APK file is, so AspNetCore will return a 404 error.

To allow this, you can map your own. REF: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0#fileextensioncontenttypeprovider

```cs
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
provider.Mappings[".apk"] = "application/vnd.android.package-archive";

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ContentTypeProvider = provider
});
```