# IFormFile for uploading .apk file ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, apk, iformfile

I have a feature in my website where I need to upload an **.apk file** which then will be available to public user. The problem is **when I choose the .apk file and click submit, it returns null object.** Below is the html code that I used in my website.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="border p-3 mt-4">
                content....
        </div>
</form>
```

I tried using different data type like .png or .pdf and this code can functioned as expected. Able to send and save the file to my database.

Any other ideas or solution on how to upload an .apk file will be much appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: What platform are you hosting on?  What does your upload method c# look like?

Comment: I used windows server with IIS. The version of ASP is ASP.NET MVC 6. The upload method is looks like this: 

[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(AppInputVersion obj)
        {
            string wwwPath = _environment.WebRootPath;
            string filename = obj.App_Version.ToString();
            .....

Comment: How IFormFile is used on your code. what is coming as null?

Comment: AspNetCore does not know what an APK file is. You can correct this by adding the mime type mapping. [See my answer other answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72894508/have-a-problem-accessing-the-files-in-wwwroot/72903102#72903102) I'm leaving this as a comment, because I do not have a snippet to get this working in a MVC Controller at this very moment

Comment: @CodingMytra I used it as one of the property in my model. The object of the model itself is null when .apk file uploaded

Comment: did your tried the solution from @AdamVincent?

Comment: @AdamVincent unfortunately your solution does not work in my case. It still return null after click submit

Comment: can put code for how are you uploading file in html page

Comment: Could you please try to check whether the browser console shows any errors while you submit the form? Have you hosted your site on any Web Server or you are testing in Visual Studio? If possible, could you please share your sample code along with your Model View and Controller? It could help get some idea about the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.